How can I upload files to Azure Blob Storage without using any libraries in Laravel?
I am puzzled and melancholy over the discontinuance of some libraries.
I wanna upload text files to Azure Blob Storage.But this function can't works.
    private static function output($path, $text): bool
    {
        $accountName = config('filesystems.disks.azure.account_name');
        $containerName = config('filesystems.disks.azure.container_name');
        $sasToken = config('filesystems.disks.azure.sas_token');
        $uri = "https://{$accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{$containerName}/{$path}";
        $version = '2024-05-04';

        $checkUri = "{$uri}?{$sasToken}";
        $checkResponse = Http::withHeaders([
            'x-ms-version' => $version,
            'x-ms-date' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'),
        ])->head($checkUri);
        
        if ($checkResponse->status() == 404) {
            $createUri = "{$uri}?{$sasToken}";
            $createResponse = Http::withHeaders([
                'x-ms-blob-type' => 'AppendBlob',
                'x-ms-date' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'),
                'x-ms-version' => $version,
            ])->put($createUri);
            
            if (!$createResponse->successful()) {
                throw new \Exception('Failed to create new blob: ' . $createResponse->body());
            }
        }

        $appendUri = "{$uri}?comp=appendblock&{$sasToken}";
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'x-ms-date' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'),
            'x-ms-version' => $version,
        ])->put($appendUri, $text);
        
        if ($response->successful()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Failed to append content: ' . $response->body());
        }
    }

Error message
I do not know the cause of this error.
Failed to create new blob: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not inn the correct format.
Time:2024-05-08T02:04:08.7165841Z</Message><HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName><HeaderValue>2</HeaderValue></Error>


If a text file of the same name already exists in AzureBlobStorage, I would like to "append" it.


encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The
value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
Time:2024-05-08T02:04:08.7165841Z</Message><HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName><HeaderValue>2</HeaderValue></Error>


The above error occurred because you have not used 'Content-Length' header in the API request.

Note: According to this MS-Document The Append Block operation is permitted only if the blob was created with x-ms-blob-type set to AppendBlob.

In my environment, I have an append blob with the name testblob.txt like below:
Portal:

Now, using the code below, it appends the blobs in my text file.
Code:
 private static function output($path, $text): bool
    {
        $accountName = config('filesystems.disks.azure.account_name');
        $containerName = config('filesystems.disks.azure.container_name');
        $sasToken = config('filesystems.disks.azure.sas_token');
        $uri = "https://{$accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{$containerName}/{$path}";
        $version = '2024-05-04';

        $checkUri = "{$uri}?{$sasToken}";
        $checkResponse = Http::withHeaders([
            'x-ms-version' => $version,
            'x-ms-date' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'),
        ])->head($checkUri);
        
        if ($checkResponse->status() == 404) {
            $createUri = "{$uri}?{$sasToken}";
            $createResponse = Http::withHeaders([
                'x-ms-blob-type' => 'AppendBlob',
                'x-ms-date' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'),
                'x-ms-version' => $version,
            ])->put($createUri);
            
            if (!$createResponse->successful()) {
                throw new \Exception('Failed to create new blob: ' . $createResponse->body());
            }
        }

        $appendUri = "{$uri}?comp=appendblock&{$sasToken}";
        $length = strlen($text);
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Length' => $length,
            'x-ms-date' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'),
            'x-ms-version' => $version,
        ])->put($appendUri, $text);
        
        if ($response->successful()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Failed to append content: ' . $response->body());
        }
    }

I provided $text='The cat sat on the mat. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'. to append the blob.
Output:
The above executed and appended successfully.

Verified by downloading the file from blob storage.
File:


But I'm getting this Error from your code...
Failed to create new blob: InvalidHeaderValueThe value for one of the HTTP headers is not inn the correct format.
Content-Length2
➜  65▕                 throw new \Exception('Failed to create new blob: ' . $createResponse->body());

What you passing content-length?

What text your appending?

Just 'This is a info message'. I write same your code. $length = strlen($text);

@vr_min_chan Is the issue is resolved?

No. But I use to mount on AppService

Please post it as answer.
